# Getting "Null" for the joined columns values after joining a shapefile and CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, csv, attribute-joins

I am trying to join one CSV file and one shapefile.

This is the shapefile attribute table:

[image: shapefile attribute table]

and this is the CSV file.

[image: CSV file]

I am getting this as the result:

[image: join result]

Does anyone know why I am getting null values in the TyincomeUsa_In... column?

[image]

Edit:
What all options do I check in this for the given problem in the case of this CSV data

Comment: what are the fields your using to join on, and what are their data types (int, string, etc?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting null values because the COUNTYNS in shapefile starts with "00" while in CSV file there is "00", which means the there is no common field IDs between shapefile and CSV file. You need to change the type of COUNTYNS field in CSV file from integer number to text and add "00" before each number. Excel will help you to do this job.

Comment: It was probably Excel that CAUSED the problem. Excel tries to infer types and probably thought that field should be numeric.

Comment: You can use TEXT Function (fx) to change the cell to string. You can refer to this help on how to do that: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/671-excel-change-number-to-text.html

Comment: @ahmadhanb can u help me what options should i check while creating a layer frm delimted file in this case

Comment: How did you save your file? Is it CSV or other delimited file?

Comment: as csv ,its csv file

Comment: Choose CSV, and also select trim fields to remove white spaces if there is any. If that did not solve the issue, then you should post another question specifying the details of your problem.

Comment: @ahmadhanb can u help me with is this question [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221379/how-to-do-weighted-overlay-analysis-with-the-csv-data-joined-with-shape-file-i]

Answer (score 0):

COUNTYNS in the shapefile is a string field and your CSV is a numeric or int field would be my guess.  Thats why they are all null

Answer (score 0):

Joining fields from two different tables is possible when one field is common in both. They act as Join and Target fields.
So, whenever you are joining fields from two attribute tables, make sure that:

1. The data type of the "Join field" and "Target field" is same.
2. Both the join and target field has same dimension.
3. The data in both the join and target fields match.