# Doing weighted overlay analysis using CSV data joined with shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, county, weighted-overlay

I have a CSV file which has data for different counties income, Population and Proximity of United States of America like this :

[image: I have a CSV file]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHf6m.png)

I have already joined the CSV file with the shapefile of United States map and duplicated them to use them as different layers.

[image]

How can I use them to do **weighted overlay analysis** to find the list of top 10 counties with respect to these 3 attributes and respective weights?

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can create new attribute with expression using **Field calculator** in attribute table. The expression would be something like:

```
("Income"*0.1)+("Population"*0.5)+("Proximity"*0.9)
```

where values (0.1, 0.5, 0.9) are coresponding weights. Than you can simple use a categorised symbology.